# Updating a profile username in mongoose, and then updating the username and data in their posts and comments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I am creating a social media application for my final project with a coding bootcamp. We are using MongoDB/Mongoose on the backend and I am having trouble trying to update the data of the user when they change their username and first / last name. Their profile is updating, their names in their posts are updating, but their comments on other people's posts are not updating.

The layout on mongoose is like this...

There is a User Profile collection. Each User Collection has a Posts collections if it exists. Each Post has Comments collection if they exist.

When the user changes their name and username, I am trying to set up the backend to change the data in all of their posts and all of their comments as well (and eventually in all notifications). But the challenge is the user can also make comments on other people's posts, So i need to also change their name on those comments as well.

Here is sample of the code...

Controller:

```
update: function (req, res) {
    db.User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, req.body, {
      new: true,
    })
      .then(function (dbUser) {
        //Updates posts from the user specified in params
        //with new pic.
        return db.Post.update(
          { _id: { $in: dbUser.posts } },
          {
            username: req.body.slug,
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
          },
          { multi: true }
        );
      })
      .then(function (req) {
        db.Comment.update(
          { userId: req.body.userId },
          {
            $set: {
              username: req.body.slug,
              firstName: req.body.firstName,
              lastName: req.body.lastName,
            },
          },
          { multi: true }
        );
      })
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
```

Models (simplified):

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  //username in lowercase
  slug: { type: String, required: true },
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  posts: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Post',
    },
  ],
  notifications: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Notification',
    },
  ],
})
```

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
  userId: { type: String, required: true },
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: String,
  postBody: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  comments: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Comment',
    },
  ],

});
```

```
const commentSchema = new Schema({
  postId: { type: String, required: true },
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  commentBody: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: String,
  userId: { type: String, required: true },
  originalPoster: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

I believe that data is being sent correctly from the front end because the user posts are updating correctly, it's just the comments within the posts that are not. Since comments are a seperate collection, I would like to write a function which scans through each comment, and if the userId = req.body.userId, update the firstName, lastNa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out FYI. I think coming here and typing out my problem helped.

```
db.Comment.find({ userId: req.params.id })
      .then(function (dbComment) {
        return db.Comment.updateMany(
          { userId: req.params.id },
          {
            $set: {
              username: req.body.slug,
              firstName: req.body.firstName,
              lastName: req.body.lastName,
            },
          },
          { multi: true }
        );
      })
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of storing the "userId", "username", "firstName" and "lastName" fields, you can just store a reference to the user. That way, you won't even need to scan through the Collection to update (this applies to both the Posts and Comments), it will just relate back to the user document. You already have relations built into your Schema, so it's just a matter of applying that same logic to the User!

Comment: Embedding documents is a valid and useful strategy to reduce reads. If the user object is rarely updated, it may make sense to embed the document to begin with.